# xdebug cashgrind.out.* files not being generated

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug, apache

I am trying to put xdebug on a centOS web server and to use its profiling capabilities in preparation for the php code that will be put on it. Currently I have apache running and installed, I installed all of the necessary php things, and also ran `pecl install xdebug` to install xdebug. I also modified the php.ini file with the line `zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so`, and now when I run `php -m` xdebug shows up in "regular modules" and "zend modules", as I understand it's supposed to. Here's a sample of my php.ini file:

```
    zend_extension="usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so"

    xdebug.profiler_enable = 1

    xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/var/www/phplogs/"
```

In my /var/www/html/ directory, I have an info.php file that reads:
        `<?php phpinfo();?>`
I restart httpd, and then use `lynx -dump localhost/info.php` (I'm ssh'd into a CLI). After running this, when I `ls /var/www/phplogs` there is nothing in the folder. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is just another annoying SELinux problem. `setenforce 0` before starting httpd with `service httpd start` and then turn it back on: `setenforce 1`. After doing this, logging should work flawlessly provided php.ini is configured as it is in the OP.